# How I can calculate the sum of two numbers loaded from another page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, console

I want to use jquery and ajax to calculate the sum of 2 numbers for exemple, but every time I try from code, the part of the code that should calculate the numbers doesn't work, but it works in console if I paste it there. The first part of the code ( the one with extracting the numbers from another page) works even in inspect element if I look, the code is there. But the one that should calculate the sum isn't. What the best solution for this?

```
$.ajax({
        success: function () {
            $('body').append('<span class="invisible-total-messages" style= "display: hidden;">*</span>');
            parseInt($('.invisible-total-messages').load('/mesaje .msglist .errorbg').hide());
            var sum = 0;
            $('.invisible-total-messages .errorbg').each(function () {
                sum += parseInt($(this).text());
            });
            if (sum !== 0) {
                $('#menu .new_messages_count').html(sum);
            }
        }      
    });
```

Comment: You need to do basic debugging. Add console.log() commands to check which functions run, what the values of your variables are, etc.

Comment: if I put all the code in console, works. But from the script, doesn't. In script works only the part where load from another page. After that, the sum isn't recognized. The sum is 0 if I run console.log.

Comment: What is the result of ``parseInt($(this).text())``? if this is null than the sumwill be 0.

Comment: I have run a console.log on "console.log(sum);" and I get 0. That is from my code. But the same code if I apply in console it gives me 12 ( the sum that I should get from my script, not just from console... )

Comment: If when the code runs, `$('.invisible-total-messages .errorbg')` is empty, then `sum` remains 0. The problem with your code is probably that the each loop runs before the .load() command finishes. You're also wrapping this in $.ajax(), which makes no sense.

Comment: Then what would be the best practice in this case? if you can help I would appreciate a lot!

Comment: Try this instead: https://pastebin.com/RzbVQN8x (the sum loop runs after the request has completed)

Comment: everything works as expected, but today I saw a small problem. The code works perfectly but only if I refresh the page. It should work immediately after the user log in. Is there a way?